# Using a For and If loop to match, index, data to a new cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have two different sized tables of data.

`Table 1` is raw data comprised of two columns:-

1. Dates = C31:C158 'Note that these WILL change
2. Transaction Amounts = D31:D158

I then have a smaller table, `Table 2`, that is also raw, with "Special Transactions" - we shall term it that now - with data in the following cells:-

1. SDates = G31:G36

I want to output the matching Transaction Amounts to the `SDates` - which are in the raw data.

I have tried different iterations of loops and I will post examples of what I have tried.

Just stumped is all. Would love some help.

```
Dim FR As Long  'FirstRow
Dim LD As Long  'Last
Dim LR As Long  'Last Row of Withdrawals

'Dim Rng As Range

FR = Cells(31, 7) 'Cell G31
LD = Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

 If IsEmpty(FR) = False Then 'If Cell C31 has additional inputs then ....

    Dim k As Long 'i
    Dim l As Long 'j

    For k = 31 To LD            
        If CLng(Cells(k, 7).Value) > DoII Then 'DoII = Start Date, it is true in my file
            For l = 31 To LR 'Column C 31: Last ROw

             EMPTY EMPTY EMPTY
            Next l










        End If
    Next k
End If
```

EDIT: Solved

Palm to Face moment code is as follows:

```
    Dim k As Long 'i
    Dim l As Long 'j

    For k = 31 To LD
        For l = 31 To LR
            If Cells(k, "H") = Cells(l, "C") Then
                Cells(k, "I") = Cells(l, "D")
            End If
        Next l
    Next k
End If
```

Comment: are tables 1 & 2 named ranges?

Comment: please correct me if i'm wrong:  my take away from your post is that you have all transaction dates in table 1, and in table 2 you only have the transaction dates (for special items); you want to `index` the amount from table 1 where the transaction date in table 2 `match` the transaction date in table 1?  if so, that can be resolved with a formula, rather than requiring VBA.

Comment: Good morning @Cyril, apologies for the delay in responding.

In answer to your first question, no. They will vary in row count with different data sets.

"ed Q. Table 1 has two columns, column 1 (c) is the dates, column 2 is the transaction amounts.

Table 2 is one column (G) Special Dates. I want the corresponding raw data from column (D) to be put into Column H.

The arrays / Tables will vary in size depending on the raw data that I have, that is why I would like to use VBA, rather than excel, this formula works:

    =INDEX($C$31:$D$156,MATCH(G31,$C$31:$C$156,0),2)